# Total measure and Riesz theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory

As I specified in the other question I asked, analysis is not my field, so I'm sorry if my question is trivial.

Riesz representation theorem states the following:

Given $X$ a locally compact hausdorff space and $\lambda$ a positive, linear and continuous functional on $C_c(X)$, there exists a unique Borel measure $\sigma_\lambda$ on $X$ for which $\lambda(f)=\int_X f d\sigma_\lambda$ for every $f\in C_c(X)$.

Now let's consider $X$ locally compact but not compact.

Given $\lambda$ and $\sigma_\lambda$ as in the theorem, I would like to compute $\sigma_\lambda(X)$ (total mass of $X$ with respect to $\sigma_\lambda$) doing computations using only the functional $\lambda$: I would like to ask you if there is a standard way to do so.

I can not set $\sigma_\lambda(X)=\lambda(1_X)$ ($1_X$ is the indicator function) since $X$ is not compact, but maybe it has sense to compute it as $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\lambda(1_{X_n})$ as $1_{X_n}$ tends to $1_{X}$ in $C_c(X)$. I don't know if it makes sense, but first of all I should find such a sequence which is not trivial to me..

Thank you

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: It is exactly as you think: $\sigma_\lambda(X) = \sup \{\lambda(f) \mid f\in C_c(X), 0\leq f\leq 1\}$.